# Snakeyaml appears to unnecessarily wrap simple values in lists

Tags: java, groovy, yaml, snakeyaml

I am attempting to parse the following YAML file using Groovy and Snakeyaml (clearly I have sanitised the data but it is sufficient to demonstrate the issue):

```
---
info:
  summary: Snakeyaml Issue
examples:
  - 1st example:
      name: Example 1
      sublist:
        - 0.1:
           foo: bar
```

I would expect the following statements:

```
println resource.info.summary
println resource.examples."1st example".name
println resource.examples."1st example".sublist."0.1"
```

to yield:

```
Snakeyaml Issue
Example 1
[foo:bar]
```

and:

```
println resource.examples."1st example".sublist."0.1".foo
```

to yield:

```
bar
```

However, the *actual* output from:

```
println resource.info.summary
println resource.examples."1st example".name
println resource.examples."1st example".sublist."0.1"
println resource.examples."1st example".sublist."0.1".foo
```

is:

```
Snakeyaml Issue
[Example 1]
[[[foo:bar]]]
[[bar]]
```

I can only get the desired output by including the list indicies:

```
println resource.info.summary
println resource.examples[0]."1st example".name
println resource.examples[0]."1st example".sublist[0]."0.1"
println resource.examples[0]."1st example".sublist[0]."0.1".foo
```

which seems unnecessary. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the structure of the data?

For completeness, the groovy code that I am using to illustrate the issue is shown below (I grabbed the CustomerResolver code off the web so that it would keep floats as strings):

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.DumperOptions
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Tag
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.resolver.Resolver

def fileName = "example.yaml"
def Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(), new Representer(), new DumperOptions(),
    new CustomResolver())
def resource = yaml.load(new File(fileName).newInputStream())

println resource.info.summary
println resource.examples."1st example".name
println resource.examples."1st example".sublist."0.1"
println resource.examples."1st example".sublist."0.1".foo

class CustomResolver extends Resolver {

    /*
     * Do not resolve float and timestamp
     */

    protected void addImplicitResolvers() {
        addImplicitResolver(Tag.BOOL, BOOL, "yYnNtTfFoO");
        addImplicitResolver(Tag.INT, INT, "-+0123456789");
        addImplicitResolver(Tag.MERGE, MERGE, "<");
        addImplicitResolver(Tag.NULL, NULL, "~nN\0");
        addImplicitResolver(Tag.NULL, EMPTY, null);

    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since the value of `sublist` is a sequence, it doesn't seem unnecessary at all that you need to indicate which element you want. That there is just one element now is no guarantee there never willl be. I would expect `println resource.examples."1st example".sublist."0.1".foo` to thrown an error.

Comment: BTW shouldn't that be `"0.1"` instead of `"blah"` in your 8th code block?

Comment: Thanks @Anthon . I've corrected the "blah" error (I'd renamed 0.1 to blah locally and removed the CustomResolver to see if that was the issue and accidentally kept it in when I made the edit); good spot.

I think I understand now. **sublist** contains a sequence of maps, the first of which has **0.1** as the key and the map **foo:bar** as the value?

Comment: Exactly, the sublist contains a sequence of maps here in block style (only requiring the dash not `[  ]`). Sometimes it helps to look at a (block-style) YAML file like that as JSON using e.g. [online yaml parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) (take care about what you paste) just to see what is there. And again: IMO leaving out the index of the sequence at the right spot should throw an error, not transparently create a list. But maybe that is a feature %-)

Comment: @Anthon I agree. I would rather it threw an exception too as this would have highlighted my misunderstanding of the data. Thanks for the JSON tip too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem in a way how you access the yaml

the `examples` first contains `list` and only then contains `object` with key `1st example`

for your case try this access:

```
println resource.info.summary
println resource.examples[0]."1st example"
println resource.examples[0]."1st example".name
println resource.examples[0]."1st example".sublist[0]
println resource.examples[0]."1st example".sublist[0]."0.1"
println resource.examples[0]."1st example".sublist[0]."0.1".foo
```

to understand how list accessor works check this example:

```
@Grab(group='org.yaml', module='snakeyaml', version='1.18')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

def Yaml yaml = new Yaml()
def resource = yaml.load(new StringReader('''---
info:
  summary: Snakeyaml Issue
examples:
  - 1st example:
      name: Example 1
  - 1st example:
      name: Example 2
  - 1st example:
      xname: Example 3
  - 2nd example:
      name: Example 4
'''))

println resource.examples."1st example"
//prints>  [[name:Example 1], [name:Example 2], [xname:Example 3], null]

println resource.examples."1st example".name
//prints> [Example 1, Example 2, null]
```

Comment: That's a really good example. Thanks @daggett. It makes sense now

Comment: @daggett Do you know if the creation of a list, when leaving out the sequence indices at the right place, is a feature? Can you actually do `println resource.examples."1st example".sublist."0.1".foo[0][0]` to get `bar`?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but as for me better to unwrap arrays at place where they appear.

Comment: I agree. I require the sequence indices in the place where they appear in a similar small Python program, callable from C++ (or other languages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39685012/1307905), but I specify them between  dots, just like the mapping keys.