# Load YAML configuration into a Groovy Map

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy

I want to read this configuration YAML from Spring Boot:

```
host:
  api1: http://api1.com
  api2: http://api2.com
  api3: http://api3.com
```

into a Map and let it create a new Object so that it looks like this:

```
def apiUrls = ["api1":new Api("http://api1.com"),
                   "api2":new Api("http://api2.com"),
                   "api3":new Api("http://api3.com")]
```

I've already tried several solutions from Stack Overflow (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24917194/spring-boot-inject-map-from-application-yml)), but the result was always an empty map. The variables are definitely loaded (they are present in /management/env).

Does anyone know how to do it in Groovy?

Comment: you can use snakeyaml. example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881499/snakeyaml-appears-to-unnecessarily-wrap-simple-values-in-lists/44882014#44882014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perhaps a bit fuzzy in the [docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding#map-based-binding), but for the maps you must:

- always provide a getter;
- either initialize the map or provide a setter.

When using Groovy, this will suffice:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "props")
class Props {
    Map<String, String> vals
}
```

It will compile roughly into

```
public class Props implements GroovyObject {
    private Map<String, String> vals;

    public Map<String, String> getVals() { return this.vals; }
    public void setVals(Map<String, String> vals) { this.vals = vals; }
}
```

If it is crucial that only a getter method is present, the class can be written as follows:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "props")
class Props {
    private Map<String, String> vals = [:]
    Map<String, String> getVals() { vals }
}
```

which will compile into something like this:

```
public class Props implements GroovyObject {
    private Map<String, String> vals;

    public Props() { /* Groovy magic including field initialization */ }

    public Map<String, String> getVals() { return this.vals; }
}
```