# Want to parse contents of yaml file in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I want some boolean parameters in Jenkins Job. Those parameters are present in a yaml file. I want to read the yam file with groovy and parse its contents and add that in parameters block of jenkinsflie.

My YAML file looks like this

zones:

```
canary_zones:
- can-1

QA_zones:
- qa-1
- qa-2

production_zones:
- prod-1
- prod-2
```

I want to read the above contents according to zone and include them in boolean paramter of jenkinfile. Is there any way to achieve that.

Comment: Show us what you've done?

Comment: As of now, I am able to read the file contents and store them in an array with-
def words = []
new File( '/root/zones.yml' ).eachLine { line ->
    words << line
}

words.each {
    println it
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881499/snakeyaml-appears-to-unnecessarily-wrap-simple-values-in-lists/44882014#44882014

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways would be to use snakeyaml:

This is a small example from the Dokumentation:
https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-loading-yaml

```
public void testLoadFromString() {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    String document = "hello: 25";
    Map map = (Map) yaml.load(document);
    assertEquals("{hello=25}", map.toString());
    assertEquals(new Long(25), map.get("hello"));
}
```